# Why ttest_ind in Scipy a little different from Excel TTest?

Tags: python, excel, scipy

Scipy(Python):

```
from scipy import stats
a=[3,4,5,8,9,1,2,4,5,3,8]
b=[6,19,3,2,14,4,5,17,1,2,4]
stats.ttest_ind(a,b, equal_var=True)
```

> Ttest_indResult(statistic=-1.0810463365416798, pvalue=0.29254014390233507)

Excel:
[image]

The result of Scipy is `0.292540`, Excel is `0.293487`. What the correct grammar to make the result of Scipy like the `TTEST(a, b, 2, 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between **paired** and **unpaired** two-sample t-tests: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests). The last parameter of Excel's `TTEST` chooses between them:

```
=TTEST(A1:K1,A2:K2,2,1)   # paired, returns   0.293487072
=TTEST(A1:K1,A2:K2,2,2)   # unpaired, returns 0.292540144
```

In SciPy, these are done by

- [`ttest_rel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) (paired; "rel" stands for *related*)
- [`ttest_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind) (unpaired, "ind" stands for *independent*)

With your a, b

```
stats.ttest_rel(a, b)                   # pvalue=0.2934870715776284
stats.ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=True)   # pvalue=0.29254014390233507
```